# Installing Julius Voice Recognition on Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: raspbian

Has anybody successfully installed Julius on a RPi3? I am trying to configure this on a Raspberry Pi 3 B running Raspian (Non-noobs install). I am trying to use a Logitech C270 webcam as my audio input device.

I have almost accomplished this using [the following steps](http://raspiprojects.com/raspberry-pi-voice-recognition-julius.html):

**1.)** `sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-oss flex zlib1g-dev libc-bin libc-dev-bin python-pexpect libasound2 libasound2-dev cvs`

**2.)** After downloading and installing the above packages I can record and play back audio with the following commands:

`arecord -d 10 -D plughw:1,0 test.wav`

`aplay test.wav`

**3.)** Download Julius form CSV with the following command:

`cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.sourceforge.jp:/cvsroot/julius co julius4`

**4.)** Export variable environment with:

`export CFLAGS="-O2 -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer"`

**5.)** Compile Julius on Raspberry Pi using the following commands

`cd julius4
./configure –with-mictype=alsa
make
sudo make install`

Unfortunately this is where I get stuck. I get an error on `./configure –with-mictype=alsa`

The configuration process reports: *(only showing the last two lines)*

> configure: error: mictype not supported, or specified type not exist
>
> configure: error: ./configure failed for libsent

After reading through the [configuration manual](https://julius.osdn.jp/juliusbook/en/desc_install.html#id2524026) for Julius I thought that perhaps setting the config to auto would work. This is done using the following command: `./configure –with-mictype=auto`

**STILL** same error. I am starting to think that there is an issue with the index of my sound capture device.

If I type in `cat /proc/asound/cards` it returns

> 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA
>
> ```
>                  bcm2835 ALSA
> ```
>
> 1 [U0x46d0x825    ]: USB-Audio - USB Device 0x46d:0x825
>
> ```
>                  USB Device 0x46d:0x825 at usb-3f980000.usb-1.3, high >speed
> ```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

did you try sudo ./configure...

you can look this too

https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/issues/40

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late (2019) but using --with... instead of -with... made a big difference.
easy to miss

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the question has already an accepted answer. So it seems the questioner doesn't have a problem with that option.